# Why do we need a Probability Mass Function?

Tags: probability, random-variables

We know that $P(X=x) = p_X(x)$

For instance, let $X$ = number of heads if two fair coins are tossed simultaneously, and $TT = 0, HT=TH=1, HH=2$.

Then we have: $P(X=1) = ( \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} ) = \frac{1}{2}$.

The same information is being conveyed by a PMF as $p_X(1) = \frac{1}{2}$.

So, why do need a PMF? Why isn't a Probability function enough?

Comment: Let $X$ be a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$.  What is the corresponding probability function?

Comment: @XanderHenderson, I don't know.

Comment: What is your definition of "probability function"?

Comment: @leonbloy, a function which gives out the probability of an event.

Comment: Okay... with reference to my last comment, suppose that $X$ is uniform on $[0,1]$.  That implies that $X$ is "equally likely" to be any number between $0$ and $1$.  What is $P(X = 0.5)$?

Comment: @XanderHenderson, in case of continuous r.v, the answer is zero.

Comment: So... it would appear that the probability function is given by $p_X(x) = 0$.  Do you recover all of the required information about the random variable from this function?

Comment: @XanderHenderson, in your case no, but, my given problem talks about discrete r.v.

Comment: Right, but how do you generalize ideas from discrete random variables to continuous random variables?  There is not really a good way to generalize a probability function to a continuous variable, but the probability mass function generalizes easily to a probability density function.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, I sort of get your idea, but I am still not being able to visualize it in my mind. Perhaps a full answer would be better.

Comment: For a continuous random variable, the probability density function gives you information about the probability at a given point.  For a uniform distribution $F(x)=P(X\le x)=x$ for $0\le x\le 1$, so the density function $f(x)=F'(x)=1$ in that domain and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a random variable $X$ that takes a finite number of values, the "probability mass function" (probability that $X$ takes each of the possible values) is indeed enough for computing the probability of any event. (And often the expressions "probability mass function" and "probability function" are used interchangeably in this context).

This is also true for a discrete random variable (i.e. a variable that takes values over a finite or countably finite support, e.g, the integers).

But it's not true for other variables. Namely, for a continuous variable that takes values over all reals (say, a uniform over the interval $[0,1]$). Here the pmf doesn't make sense, because $P(X=x)=0$ for all $x$.

An alternative is the [cumulative distribution function](http://Cumulative%20distribution%20function) (CDF) that is well defined for a real random variable, no matter it's discrete or continuous (or anything), and fully characterizes the probability distribution. If the CDF is derivable, the derivative is called the [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) - this is conceptually analogous (but not the same) as the PMF , for continuous variables.

Comment: Okay. So, my suspect was correct .... :)

Comment: Of course, all of this is properly handled in the context of measure theory, where a discrete probability corresponds to an integral taken with respect to counting measure.  In that context, a pmf and a pdf are really the same thing. :)

Comment: It seems to me like this answers the reverse of the question asked. OP asks whether a probability function is enough, and why we need a PMF (and in the comments, clarifies that a probability function is a function defined on events). This answer here says that a PMF is not enough, and explains why we need a probability function (or something similar).

Comment: @JulianRosen, that gives you a great opportunity to post an answer...

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, you clarify that a probability function is the function taking an event to its probability. You are correct that a probability function is enough to recover the PMF. However, for a discrete random variable, the probability function has lots of redundant data (given by the axioms of probability), whereas the PMF does not.

For example, let $X$ be the outcome when a weighted die is rolled. The events are the subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. There are $64$ events, so it might seem like we would have to give $64$ values to describe the probability function. However, the PMF only takes on $6$ values (the probabilities of rolling each individual number), and describing these $6$ values is enough to recover the probability function. So it is much faster to write down the PMF than to write down the probability function.